# POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE no working on docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, passwords

I am working with the following yaml and postgres_password_file, but it is not working. I have checked that the file inside container is correct and user/permissions of the file are correct. Postgres is creating postgres user but I cant find any password that fits that user, at the same time is not creating dbUser.

I don't know what to check or what else to do. Do you have any ideas of why it is not working correctly?

Thanks in advance

yaml:

```
version: '2'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:11
    restart: always
    user: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/pgpassfile
    secrets:
      - pgpassfile

secrets:
  pgpassfile:
    file: ./pgpassfile
```

pgpassfile own by postgres(999) inside and outside is:

```
*:5432:*:dbUser:password
```

postgres server log:

```
[+] Running 2/2                                                       
 ✔ Network scripts_default  Created                                                                       0.1s 
 ✔ Container scripts-db-1   Created                                                                       0.2s 
Attaching to db-1                                                                                              
db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db-1  | This user must also own the server process.          
db-1  |                                                                       
db-1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db-1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db-1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".       
db-1  |                                                           
db-1  | Data page checksums are disabled.                    
db-1  |                                                                       
db-1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db-1  | creating subdirectories ... ok                       
db-1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100                             
db-1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB    
db-1  | selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
db-1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix                                               
db-1  | creating configuration files ... ok
db-1  | running bootstrap script ... ok                                       
db-1  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db-1  | 
db-1  | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db-1  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db-1  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db-1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
db-1  | 
db-1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db-1  | 
db-1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db-1  | 
db-1  | waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-09 13:52:25 UTC
db-1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db-1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db-1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db-1  |  done
db-1  | server started
db-1  | 
db-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db-1  | 
db-1  | LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db-1  | waiting for server to shut down...LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db-1  | .LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db-1  | LOG:  shutting down
db-1  | LOG:  database system is shut down
db-1  |  done
db-1  | server stopped
db-1  | 
db-1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db-1  | 
db-1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-09 13:52:27 UTC
db-1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db-1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db-1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Answer (score 0):

POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE is not a way to set the .pgpass file, (which also wouldn't make much sense since .pgpass is a client thing, not a server thing).  It is an alternate way of setting POSTGRES_PASSWORD.

So what you did here was initialized the password for the 'postgres' user to be the string '*:5432:*:dbUser:password'

Answer (score 0):

that is my postgre sample in docker-compose.yml.

```
postgres:
 container_name: postgres
 image: postgres
 environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: changeme
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
  PGDATA: /data/postgres
 volumes:
   - ./postgres:/data/postgres
 ports:
   - "5432:5432"
 networks:
   - elastic
 restart: unless-stopped
```